# I didn't success to call a servlet inside another servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dispatcher, requestdispatcher

I have servlet A where there is this code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("gestion-avis");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

And then another servlet B which refers to "gestion-avis" :

```
@WebServlet("/gestion-avis")
public class GestionAvisServlet extends HttpServlet
```

The code of the A servlet normally redirect to the doGet method of the servlet B.

But this redirect me to an empty html page called "gestion-avis".

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason for your issue.

Since you are forwarding request to another servlet mapped at url `gestion-avis`, the request goes to your `GestionAvisServlet` and its `doGet` method.

Now if your `GestionAvisServlet.doGet` method is not writing any data to `HttpServletResponse`, you will get a blank screen.

So to see some data either you need to write data to `HttpServletResponse` like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello");
 }
```

Otherwise you can forward to another page.

Comment: But at runtime this is not entering in the method GestionAvisServlet.doGet.

Comment: I don't want to write something, i want to forward the request to another jsp page

Comment: The program just don't enter in GestionAvisServlet.doGet

Comment: Actually when I do request.getRequestDispatcher("gestion-avis"), this enter to the GestionAvisServlet.doPost() method, and not the doGet()...